# Is it permitted to make wudu during adhan?

Tags: taharah, adhan

It is happening most of the times for maghrib prayer.

When I'm making wudu for prayer, the adhan was made. At this time, how I should respond to adhan?

Is it permitted to make wudu during adhan?

(I can ask this as)

Is it permitted to respond to adhan while making ablution?

Comment: you still reply to it but only if you are not in front of napaak things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is permissible to perform wudu' during adhan & also respond to adhan while performing wadhu. Because I saw a Mufti performing wudu' at the time of Asr or Maghrib adhan(I don't remember properly) in Ablution area in mosque & he was also replying to the adhan while performing wudu'. He is a Mufti from Deoband madrassa in India.

Comment: Assalamu alaikum and welcome to islam.SE, the question is about the general rules about making wudu during adhan, that mufthi sha'ab you mentioned might had some other hurries or needs we didn't know that, so, we can't judge the answer from that, here islam.SE we require answers more authentic, jazakallah and +1 for answer, keep contributing and make this site useful to our ummat

Answer (score 1):

**Is it permitted to make wudu during adhan?**

Yes, as this is Mubah and there is no proof in the Shariah that prohibits this.

**Is it permitted to respond to adhan while making ablution?**

Yes, as to repeat the Adhan should be by anyone in whatever state they are as the Adhan is Zikr, the exception is those who are in Salat, or in the toilet, or during the fulfilment of the desire with one mate.

The Prophet ﷺ said:

> ‏إذا سمعتم النداء، فقولوا كما يقول المؤذن
>
> When you hear the Mu'adhdhin (pronouncing the call to Salat), repeat
>   after him what he says.

[متفق عليه](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/48)

Also Annawawi said in [المجموع شرح المهذب](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=14&ID=1449):

> قال أصحابنا : ويستحب متابعته لكل سامع من طاهر ومحدث وجنب وحائض وكبير
>   وصغير ; لأنه ذكر . وكل هؤلاء من أهل الذكر ، ويستثنى من هذا المصلي ومن
>   هو على الخلاء والجماع

***NOTE: the following is not exact translation***:

> Our companions said: and it is liked to repeat it for whoever hears it
>   from one who is pure to one who is impure, from old to young; because
>   it is Zikr.  and all of the mentions are of the people of zikr, and
>   the exception are those who are making salat and those who are in the
>   toilet or with his wife.